# Gradle sync failed: Failed to create parent directory

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin

I've faced a problem during the installation process of the android studio. I've ignored the failure at the start and after creating a project,it stated that "Gradle sync failed: Failed to create parent directory".

I've downloaded most SDK and searched for possible answers online but I'm still not able to solve the problems.

Please provide me with all the help possible. Thank you

Comment: Do you have access permissions in the location you are trying to create your project?

Comment: did your check project location and clean rebuild your project...?

Comment: Re install your android studio...

Comment: I did try to re-install multiple times but it is still not working.

Gradle sync failed: Failed to create parent directory: org.sonatype.oss oss-parent 

How do i clean rebuild my project? I've tried to build multiple projects and still get the same error.

Comment: @AndyOng :don't re-install studio again and again.. better download different versions of android studio and simply create new project and check again if its giving same error again or not? If you are facing same problem then there is problem with the installation of studio.

The problem might be due to the wifi firewall (I faced this problem months ago and later I found that my wifi firewall was restricting me to download important components)

(y)

Comment: There's a problem with the installation of studio as it was states:
Error opening file for writing:
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\m2repository\org\sonatype\oss\oss-parent\7\oss-parent-7.pom.

How do i then allow my wifi firewall to download some major components?

Answer (score 24):

In my case, I have pulled my repository, and it was displaying this error. To fix,  just run the commands:

```
flutter clean
```

and then:

```
flutter run
```

Comment: That solves the problem ... Thanks for your help

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

It is because android studio needs admin privilege to create directory in that path.
So, to solve this problem simply **run** android studio **as administrator**

Comment: for mac users??

Comment: @ArmaniDarknight If you are on Admin account the sudo command lets you launch applications with root access. Enter sudo "\file path from hard drive to application.app/Contents/MacOS/application name".  But If you are not on admin account, Enter the command su - followed by a space and an administrator's username on this computer. Enter that administrator's password. You are now operating as that user.

Comment: As a windows user, this seems un-necessarily complicated.  Is there any to make this work easily without launching it from terminal as sudo?  Is there a preferred path that would make admin privilege unnecessary?

Answer (score 6):

Look at the location its failing to create, go to that location and delete cache folder, worked for me

Comment: +1 my gradle build started failing in Intellij because the <project> build parent dir was corrupt or something, so the <build>/classes dir couldn't be created.  Deleting the build dir in (Windows) Explorer worked to resolve the issue for me.

Answer (score 5):

deleting the build folder in the android/app directory fix my problem

Answer (score 2):

I run `chown -R user:user /path/to/.gradle`.

I found some of the directories had been owned by root. Maybe its because, during software update, i was forced to run Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA as root due to installing them under `/usr/local`

Answer (score 1):

delete the build folder in the android/app

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32770675)

Answer (score 0):

If you are building project on same computer just run flutter clean and then invalidate caches and restart project.
else delete build folder from project directory.

Answer (score 0):

My case:
It failed because not find the old path. I have to delete the folder: android/app/build. And flutter run again.

Answer (score 0):

Using Linux, VSCode:
I faced this problem after shifting my project to a different computer.
I solved this by deleting `android/app/build/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you face this kind of issue: FAILED TO CREATE PARENT DIRECTORY, then simply

- Delete the build folder from the root directory of the project, and
- Run the project again.