# How to change path of parent directory?I have took project from my friend but the parent directory is showing his folders how can I change it?

Tags: flutter, android-studio

How can I change this parent directory?
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jthMk.jpg

Comment: It has been asked before. Does that Link help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810668/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-create-parent-directory

Comment: No actually I took this project from my friend and now the path is showing his folders..how can I change that path..please do tell

Comment: Make a backup before but did you try deleting the build folder in the android/app directory?

Comment: Can you elaborate?I didn't understand

Comment: What exactly didn't you understand? What I am guessing is that it contains the path of your friend because you didn't clean your projects build folder so go to android/app directory and delete the build folder under the mentioned precautions

Comment: I have to delete build.gradle file??

Comment: No. Please take a look at that ressource: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38810668/gradle-sync-failed-failed-to-create-parent-directory